# Python: How to Send Text/CSV Content From API Request to Google Cloud Storage Asynchronously?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, google-cloud-storage, python-asyncio

I am looking to download the Text/CSV content from an API (which takes around 5-6 minutes to finish downloading for each API call) and then send the content to Cloud Storage as csv files. I'm using Python's Async library to do these API Requests and the loading of CSV files to cloud storage asynchronously.

Here's my first stab at this, but I'm unsure if I'm doing it correctly. Would welcome any insight/guidance?

Python Code:

```
async def upload_to_bucket_async(bucket_name, folder, dataset_id, timestamp, blob_name, file_obj):
    """Upload CSV Files to Cloud Storage Buckets"""

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        storage = Storage(session=session)
        status = await storage.upload(bucket_name, f'{folder}/{dataset_id}/{timestamp}/{blob_name}', file_obj)
        return status

async def get_csv_async(
              session: aiohttp.ClientSession,
              url,
              version,
              dataset_id,
              timestamp,
              bucket_name,
              token,
              **kwargs
              ):

    async with session.get(
            url % (dataset_id, timestamp),
            headers={
            'Authorization': 'token ' + token,
            'X-API-Version': version,
            'Accept': 'text/csv',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'
        },
            **kwargs) as response:

        res = await upload_to_bucket_async(bucket_name=bucket_name,
                                     folder="thinknum",
                                     dataset_id=dataset_id,
                                     timestamp=timestamp,
                                     blob_name="data.csv",
                                     file_obj=await response.read()
                                     )

        return url % (dataset_id, timestamp), res

async def get_all_csvs_async(url, version, dataset_id, timestamps, bucket_name, token, **kwargs):
    timeout = ClientTimeout(total=900)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=timeout) as session:

        futures = [get_csv_async(session=session, url=url, version=version, dataset_id=dataset_id, timestamp=t,
                                 bucket_name=bucket_name, token=token,
                                 **kwargs) for t in timestamps]

        return await asyncio.gather(*futures, return_exceptions=True)


def run_calls(self, token, dataset_id, timestamps, batch_size):
    ts_in_batches = list(chunks(timestamps, batch_size))
    self.log(msg='Running API Calls to ThinkNum for Retrieving History (%s batches)' % len(ts_in_batches),
             level=logging.INFO)

    all_history = []
    for ts in ts_in_batches:
        res = asyncio.run(get_all_csvs_async(self.csv_data_endpoint, self.version, dataset_id, ts, self.bucket_name, token))
        all_history.append(res)

    self.log(msg='Successfully Completed API Calls to ThinkNum for All Batches', level=logging.INFO)

    return all_history
```

Comment: `upload_to_bucket_async` creates a brand new session on each invocation, although the caller has a session already. Why don't you pass the session to `upload_to_bucket_async`? That way it could reuse sockets and other resources.

Comment: Also, the `for ts in ts_in_batches` loop should probably be in an `async def`. You should run `asyncio.run()` only once because it creates a fresh new event loop each time around.

Comment: Thanks so much - these are good catches!